# How fast should I expect postgresql to be?

Tags: postgresql, performance

I'm assessing postgresql performance for a time-series application, particularly for inserts. I'm running the speed test script from `sqlalchemy` at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/performance.html#i-m-inserting-400-000-rows-with-the-orm-and-it-s-really-slow. You can ignore the ORM stuff, it's the penultimate "core" line which shows the performance.

I was expecting to see from 10 to 100k writes per second as per e.g. (https://docs.timescale.com/latest/introduction/timescaledb-vs-postgres):
[image: PostgreSQL and Timescale comparison]

However, I'm instead getting the following:

[image: Performance test results]

So that's 358 writes per second! Compared to 83k writes per second for sqlite.

That seems really slow to me, but I'm getting this performance consistently across a Windows installation, Docker on Windows, native Ubuntu and Docker on Ubuntu.

Are my expectations just misaligned with reality, or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

To clarify, I'm not using Timescale DB's hyptertables feature yet, just plain vanilla PostgreSQL tables. I am using the TimescaleDB docker installation for my docker tests (though not the native test). Specifically, I'm invoking

```
docker run -d --rm -p 5433:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password timescale/timescaledb:latest-pg12
```

Comment: Both machines are running a local SSD

Answer (score 5):

The trick to getting good performance out of PostgreSQL for inserts using SQLAlchemy is, as @LaurenzAlb hinted at, better management of transactions. SQLAlchemy can, but doesn't by default, use psycopg2's `executemany` helpers for PostgreSQL.

Turning these on transforms performance for multiple inserts into the same table. Here's the modified code for the python test.

```
    engine = create_engine(DB_NAME, echo=False, executemany_mode='values')
```

With `executemany_mode=None`:

```
SQLAlchemy Core: Total time for 50000 records 95.0814561843872 secs = 525.8648952855459 /s
```

with `executemany_mode="values"`:

```
SQLAlchemy Core: Total time for 50000 records 1.761573314666748 secs = 28383.71788656377 /s
```

See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#psycopg2-batch-mode for an explanation.